Methodology of the Cass review
This week Dr Hilary Cass published her report on the review of gender identity services for children and young people. The report is on a divisive topic, and though I have my opinion, in this question I am not here for arguments on the basic issue, I would merely like to know what medical researchers think about the methodology of the report.
This is a meta review, it seeks to aggregate information from a lot of former studies. Not all studies are the same quality, and a lot of studies were dismissed by the review as being too low quality. (For an introduction to this idea, see this unrelated medical paper's section on inclusion criteria. ) 
There is a claim going around that most of these dismissed studies have shown a positive effect of some gender identity services, while the studies accepted by the report have mostly shown a negative or close to neutral effect of the same services, raising concerns about biased dismissal.
There is some disagreement about whether it was fair to require 'double-blindness' from the interventions in these studies, and whether it was actually a requirement, or whether they used the more complex Newcastle-Ottawa Scale.
So basically I would like to know if medical researchers think that the Cass review had  methodological problems in these or other areas.
Again, I have my own opinion on the basic issue, but here I would insist that the researchers you cite in your answer are not Dr. X from the Clearly-Involved-In-This Foundation or Senior Expert Y from the We-Get-A-Lot-Of-Money Think Tank. I am not saying advocacy is necessarily wrong, but methodological problems are value neutral and can be pointed out in such a way. Please feel free to post your own question where you are also seeking answers from more involved parties, but don't post those answers/comments here.

I got the request to reference a notable claim to be skeptical about: 
The implicit notable claim is that the Cass review is scientific without methodological problems. Some have cast doubt on this. Is there reason to be skeptical about the Cass review or can we accept its findings?

According to the FAQ, Skeptics.SE is for researching the evidence behind the claims you hear or read. This question doesn't appear to have any doubtful claims to investigate. Please edit it to reference a notable claim and flag for moderator attention to re-open (or get 5 re-open votes).

"The methodology" as a whole isn't a claim. Is there a particular statement that you doubt? The idea that poor-quality research might reach different conclusions to high-quality research isn't a red flag; it occurs in homeopathy, acupuncture and a number of other areas of pseudoscience.

I have both edited the question and raised a flag to make the central claim (that the Cass review is a proper scientific work) more clear.

"The idea that poor-quality research might reach different conclusions to high-quality research isn't a red flag" I don't doubt this, nor is it an issue in the question? The question says that some are skeptical about whether quality assessment was unbiased in this study.

At present this is very broad and lacking an explicit claim for us to test. To perform an analysis of the whole paper with its many points is way too broad for what we do here.

@JiminyCricket. I could see the point in being a narrower SE, but looking at the other questions, this does not seem to be true? E.g.; https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56772/does-gender-transitioning-do-nothing-to-help-suicidal-ideation is also asking about the thesis of a study, as is this one https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/44959/can-john-gottman-predict-which-couples-will-divorce-with-extremely-high-accuracy?

@JiminyCricket. Would it solve the problem if I narrowed it specifically to inclusion criteria and not ask about other methodological problems?

Those were studies with a single tested claim in each case whereas you've presented us with a review-paper which contains multiple claims to test. Can you narrow it down in some dimension, I'm not sure inclusion criteria fits, but you can try.

Okay, having browsed this SE a bit, and I think I had a different image of it than what it is, because some questions had nice physics and probabilistic details, other questions are indeed much more straightforward. If you think I am unlikely to get a good answer, I'll accept your opinion.

I downloaded the final report, and it was not as you described. It isn't a scientific study; it is a review to make policy recommendations to a political body. It is not a meta analysis - but it commissioned many systematic reviews. So the questions you are raising about inclusion criteria seem to be on the wrong document(s). Please link and quote the people who are making the accusations about the review so we can see what they are really saying.

Meanwhile, this is a 388 page document that has just been released. If you want proper post-publication review of it, you will need to wait.

Re: Red flags. You wrote: "There is a claim going around that most of these dismissed studies have shown a positive effect of some gender identity services, while the studies accepted by the report have mostly shown a negative or close to neutral effect of the same services, raising concerns about biased dismissal." and I pointed out that the former is not a red flag for the latter.  So, yes it is an issue for the question as written.

@Oddthinking I will have another look at it, I honestly thought it reviewed and aggregated papers per subject. I understand and agree that more time will be necessary for a proper review, though there was a midterm report 2 years ago, so the methodology on what studies to include could have already been peer reviewed. I still don't understand your point on how dismissing studies which lean in one direction would not be a concern. I do not claim it is proof of bias, just something to be examined. Anyway, I will not contest the closure of the question, thank you for your time.
